# Multiple conditions in a While Loop - IDL

Tags: loops, syntax, while-loop, syntax-error, idl-programming-language

I am trying to create a multiple condition while loop in IDL with no success. For example:

```
while (delta_flux gt 1.0) or (lt -1.0) do begin
;something here...
endwhile
```

returns:

```
IDL> .run flare_finder_while_attempt5.pro

      while (delta_flux gt 1.0) or (lt -1.0) do begin
                                    ^
% Syntax error.
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
while (delta_flux gt 1.0) or (delta_flux lt -1.0) do begin
```